# Tell the library to create spherical panoramas

Tags: opencv

I want to create a site that will take the original images and create a spherical panorama of them. I plan to use the finished library, but I do not know which one has this feature. I watched OpenCV, but I didn’t understand whether it could create spherical panoramas from a set of photos. Perhaps someone had experience with this issue.

Comment: As a starting point, have a look at [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html) tutorial.

Comment: This is a simple demo: [Compute coordinates from source images after stitching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904718/compute-coordinates-from-source-images-after-stitching/54953792#54953792) You only need to change `Ptr<WarperCreator> warper_creator = makePtr<cv::CylindricalWarper>();` to `Ptr<WarperCreator> warper_creator = makePtr<cv::SphericalWarper>();`