# Remapping opencv stitched images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-stitching

I am using opencv class stitcher to stitch multiple images. Stitching is working fine, now I want to remap the images back into the stitched image. Basically I want to draw rectangles where the images where stitched.Any lead how I can achieve it. TA

Here is the simple code for stitching:

```
import cv2

stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(True)

img1 = cv2.imread("images1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("images2.jpg")
img3 = cv2.imread("images3.jpg")


result = stitcher.stitch((img1,img2,img3))

cv2.imshow("camera",result[1])
cv2.imwrite('/home/ign/Documents/Mostafiz/tec_Track/data/images/stitched.png',result[1])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

here are the sample images [image: s1],[image: s2],[image: s3]

Comment: Maybe it helps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904718/compute-coordinates-from-source-images-after-stitching/54953792#54953792](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904718/compute-coordinates-from-source-images-after-stitching/54953792#54953792)

Comment: Thanks, but they are using some blender and all for doing the stitching, here I am just using the opencv stitching function, so not able to implement that.